# Проблемы с анимацией jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть код, который выполняется при вызове функции theBestFunction:

```
if ( $(objName).css('display') == 'none' ) {
    $(objName).animate({height: 'show'}, 300);
    document.getElementById('mobile_menu_bg_inv').style.display = "none";
    } else {
    $(objName).animate({height: 'hide'}, 300);
    document.getElementById('mobile_menu_bg_inv').style.display = "block";
    }
```

Вроде бы, всё прекрасно. Но строка кода "document.getElement..." выполняется раньше, чем $(objName).animate(). Можете объяснить - почему и как это исправить?
PS: извиняюсь, если это глупый вопрос, просто недавно начал что-либо вообще делать с помощью JS :S

Answer (score 0):

Не раньше - сразу после входа в $(objName).animate, но для глаза это параллельное выполнение. Если надо после - спользуте коллбек функцию.

```js
let objName = $('.obj-name');

if (objName.css('display') == 'none' ) {
    objName.animate({height: 'show'}, 300, function() {
        document.getElementById('mobile_menu_bg_inv').style.display = "none";
    });
} else {
    objName.animate({height: 'hide'}, 600, function() {
        document.getElementById('mobile_menu_bg_inv').style.display = "block";
    });
}
```

```css
#mobile_menu_bg_inv{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obj-name">qwe</div>
<div id="mobile_menu_bg_inv">rty</div>
```